# Can't insert value in database from

Tags: php, html, database, insert

I have to insert some value into a database but it doesn't work no error is displayed when I submit the form.

The form has got some dropdowns.

This is the php code in the file "insert_alim.php":

```
<?php 

$Nome= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Nome');
$Categoria = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Categoria');
$Data_Scad= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Data_Scad');
$Data_Scad_Fin = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Data_Scad_Fin');
$Quantita = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Quantita');
$unita = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'unita');
$prezzo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prezzo');

$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "alimenti";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_errno() .') '
    . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO alimenti(Nome, Categoria, Data_Scad, Data_Scad_Fin,             
Quantita, unita, prezzo)
    values ('$Nome', '$Categoria', '$Data_Scad', '$Data_Scad_Fin', 
'$Quantita', '$unita', '$prezzo' )";

    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "Complimneti il tuo alimento è stato inserito!";
}
    else {
        echo "Errore";
    }
$conn->close();
}
    ?>
```

This is the html code in the file "Aggiungi Alimento.php":

```
<form action = "insert_alim.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="Nome" placeholder="Nome Alimento"><br/>
  <select  name="Categoria" action = "insert_alim.php" method="post" >
      <option disabled selected value>Seleziona Categoria</option>
      <option value="Carne">Carne</option>
      <option value="Pesce">Pesce</option>
      <option value="Verdura">Verdura</option>
      <option value="Frutta">Frutta</option>
      <option value="Latticini">Latticini</option>
    </select>
<input type="date" name="Data_Scad">
  <input type="date" name="Data_Scad_Fin">
  <input type="text" name="Quantita" placeholder="Quantità"><br/>

  <select  name="unita" action = "insert_alim.php" method="post">
      <option value="kg">Kg</option>
      <option value="gr">gr</option>
      <option value="litri">Litri</option>
      <option value="pezzi">Pezzi</option>
    </select>
  <input type="text" name="prezzo" placeholder="Prezzo">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Inserisci" />
```

Thank You Very Much To Everyone For The Help.

Comment: `<select  name="unita" action = "insert_alim.php" method="post">` is strange mark up. Maybe your form isn't being processed correctly because of that. What behavior do you get when you submit?

Comment: Just a tip, the code contains an SQL injection point: `('$Nome', '$Categoria', '$Data_Scad', '$Data_Scad_Fin', 
'$Quantita', '$unita', '$prezzo' )`. Better use prepared statements.

Comment: Does your if statement, `$conn->query($sql)` return the message error, or does it say success?

Comment: action = "insert_alim.php", but your file is called "insert_alimento.php" (This is the php code in the file "insert_alimento.php":...)

Comment: when I submit insert_alim.php returns: "Errore" but if in the same echo I try to write the code to display the value that has to be submitted from the html all the value are ok. @user3783243

Comment: @ReesMorris, return Errore, see the answer above, I can't find a way to tag also you in the same post, thanks

Comment: Yes, my fault, I typed wrong here, the file is insert_alim.php

Thanks @jibsteroos

Comment: Yes, thank you I see some videos about it @DanielO